# Is 'non-threaded' a synonym of 'single threaded'?

Tags: multithreading, single-threaded

Apache web server documentation says prefork mpm implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server. And I'm a little bit confused about the term 'non-threaded'.

Is 'non-threaded' a synonym of 'single threaded'?

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html

Comment: Roughly.  There will be one thread per process.  You'll however have a lot of processes.  It is intended as a solution to a web server that needs to use code that is not thread-safe.  Isolating the state of that code in each separate process makes it thread-safe.

Comment: A "Routine" is perhaps the word you're looking for.